# environment specific config with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am working on creating a website with Angularjs and WebAPI as backend support with Visual studio.

I have defined the url to webapi in app.config.js as an app constant:

```
    var serviceBase = 'http://localhost/Webapiservice/';
    app.constant('ngAppSettings', {
        apiServiceBaseUri: serviceBase,
        clientId: 'ngTestApp'
    });
```

Now for QA environments (`http://QAServer/Webapiservice/`), the webapi resides at a different URL, the same goes for our production environment (`http://ProdServer/Webapiservice/`).

I can manually update the js file to the appropriate location. But is there a way to automate this process so webAPI is pointing to the correct URL?

Is it possible to do this with grunt? Again I have never used grunt before.

Comment: on which server you are hosting the website?

Answer (score 0):

`ngConstant` does a great job, along with grunt: https://github.com/werk85/grunt-ng-constant. This way you can specify your environments as JSON files and on compile/run time, grunt generates a `enviornment.js` file with a module (I call mine always `ENV`), which can be injected in every part of your application.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .value('$path', {
      rest : "http://localhost/Webapiservice"
  })
```

you will call something like this:

```
app.constant('ngAppSettings', {
    apiServiceBaseUri: $path.rest,
    clientId: 'ngTestApp'
});
```